# Convert Kotlin "file" to Kotlin "class"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

a simple one that I still can't figure out myself.
I am working on a student project for school and use android studio's to make something in Kotlin.

I have two different types of
 [Kotlin "files"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTmRo.png) here:

How can I convert the lower one (the one with a file symbole) to the same as the upper one (the one with the class symbole)?

That's all, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have more then one class in your "file"?

Comment: No, I only have one in each "file".

Comment: Both files have a same extension ".kt". Why would it one have extension and other not? Simply because your fragmentITJokes.kt file contains several classes or your file name != class name. How you can deal with it? In case with several classes just separate it, in case with different naming just refactor/rename class or file.

Comment: would probably help your question out by _showing_ the content of the file

Comment: Dont put up screen shots. Code is text, so please see [mcve] and give us meaningful input as nicely formatted/indented text.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Answer (score 1):

1. You probably have a different name for the file and class name inside the file. Make sure your "fragmentlTJokes.kt" has the same class name as" "fragmentlTJokes" inside the file.

OR

2. You might be having more than one class definition inside your "fragmentlTJokes.kt".